# Get a blank page after pushing a site using Github pages with Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I created a GitHub Pages site with Jekyll. Everything is fine when browsing to http://localhost:4000.

Then I pushed it to GitHub, but there is nothing (blank page, no error, no content) when accessing  [https://USERNAME.github.io/](https://username.github.io/).

The content of `Gemfile`,

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby RUBY_VERSION

gem "minima", "~> 2.0"

gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

group :jekyll_plugins do
   gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
end
```

The structure of my repo, (why is `_site` not uploaded?)

```
_posts        Initial commit for Jekyll             23 hours ago
.gitignore    Initial commit for Jekyll             23 hours ago
Gemfile       Uncomment some lines for GitHub Pages 23 hours ago
Gemfile.lock  Initial commit for Jekyll             23 hours ago
_config.yml   Initial commit for Jekyll             23 hours ago
about.md      Initial commit for Jekyll             23 hours ago
index.md      Initial commit for Jekyll             23 hours ago
```

Do I miss some steps?

Comment: Did you push to the gh-pages branch? The site directory does not belong to the repository, so that is correct.

Comment: @JoostS, I firstly push to the *master* branch, and later push to the *gh-pages* branch.

Comment: A real repository url can help for debug.

Comment: I have this same issues. Did you solve it?

Comment: https://sparkandshine.github.io/ 
GitHub Pages updated to Jekyll 3.3, it seems to fix the blank page problem.

Comment: @DirtyF, thank u so much. Actually my problem isn't solved. [sparkandshine.github.io](https://sparkandshine.github.io/) is forked from a repo. My previous repo is renamed as [sparkandshine2.github.io](https://github.com/sparkandshine/sparkandshine2.github.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_site` was not uploaded because it is in your [.gitignore](https://github.com/sparkandshine/sparkandshine.github.io/blob/master/.gitignore) file.

["GitHub Pages manages your site's build process with a single push to your site's publishing branch"](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-pages-and-jekyll/#jekylls-build-process) so you do not need to upload the files of a built site.

Verify your site is being built from the source folder you intend. See [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#default-source-settings-for-repositories-without-the-username-naming-scheme).

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem when I've tried to use `theme` which is not supported by GitHub Pages.

Then I've found out that GitHub Pages support custom themes: https://blog.github.com/2017-11-29-use-any-theme-with-github-pages/

For example in my case I wanted to use this theme which is in a gem: https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes

And instead of changing `theme` in `_config` I had to add `remote_theme: remote_theme: mmistakes/minimal-mistakes`