# Github pages published but nothing shows up

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I built a Jekyll site locally (Jekyll version 4.1.1) and the theme I'm using is Hydeout 4.1.0. The site runs fine locally. I've pushed it to my repository on github and it says the site is published, but the page loads to just a white space.

Comment: Did you look in the network tab? Probably the routes to the assets are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change `theme: jekyll-theme-hydeout` to `remote_theme: fongandrew/hydeout` and it is working.

I am creating you a pull request on your repo incorporating this change.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52103672/11474769
and usage section of this https://github.com/fongandrew/hydeout/